# Decorators in Go, code-style matters

Tags: go, coding-style, decorator

So I have a decorator-like function to format functions output as markdown code block.
Someting like this:

````
func mdFormat(f func() string) (func() string) {

    return func() string {
        return(fmt.Sprintf("```\n%s\n```", f()))
    }
}
````

Is it actually OK to do it with such function or is there any better solutions that I don't see?

Comment: That seems like a perfectly reasonable decorator.